# how to get the pagination url's

Tags: java, httpclient, jsoup

Im using HTTPClient and Jsoup to get the urls and navigate through the pages. I have a scenario where a single link has 3 or 4 pages controlled by pagination. onSubmit of each number, action is posted and url gets changed and navigation is done. How can i get this urls from the main page?

this is how my pagination exists in UI

```
<div class="pagination">
<div class="label">Page: </div>         
<div class="button selected" onclick="$('.page-position', $(this).closest('form')).attr('value', $(this).html()); $(this).closest('form').submit();">1</div>        
<div class="button " onclick="$('.page-position', $(this).closest('form')).attr('value', $(this).html()); $(this).closest('form').submit();">2</div>
<div class="button " onclick="$('.page-position', $(this).closest('form')).attr('value', $(this).html()); $(this).closest('form').submit();">3</div>            
<div class="button" onclick="$('.page-position', $(this).closest('form')).attr('value', 2);$(this).closest('form').submit();">Next</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no way we know how your documents are paginated! Downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsoup parses static HTML. The URLs are created by Javascript/JQuery. So you can't do it with Jsoup. You could try [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) to create the page and render the Javascript, then it is simple to select the divs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the page you are trying to get at. Most websites this days have very well structured url so it really boils down to how easy it is to interpret the url. You can use firebug on firefox to get at the css path / xpath and use jsoup 
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

If on the other hand the site have unstructured url, then simply naviagate it like you would using a browser, that is, going back and forth. Use the first page with the links as an anchor, then go back and forward. On Python you can do this using mechanize.